# Karate Framework cannot override ssl

Tags: ssl, selenium-chromedriver, ssl-certificate, karate

I am trying to use the stand alone Karate .jar file in docker. I am connecting that to my Selenium Grid docker containers. I need to run this on Jenkins so I wanted to utilize the existing infrastructure of selenium grid.

I have a simple test to navigate to google and search for something. I am getting 'Privacy Error'. I tried to use 'acceptInsecureCerts' and I have tried 'configure ssl = true' and I have tried 'configure ssl = { trustAll: true }'. Nothing seems to work.

I would like to know what I am doing wrong. Am I not using these correctly? Do I need to do something else instead?

I have this feature that calls another feature which calls another feature. This is so I can test Chrome, Edge and Firefox.

```
Feature: Example UI Test Suite for testing all browsers

    Background:
        # * configure ssl = true
        * configure ssl = { trustAll: true }

    Scenario:
        * karate.call('ExampleUITestChromeDriver.feature')
        # * karate.call('ExampleUITestGeckoDriver.feature')
        # * karate.call('ExampleUITestMSEdgeDriver.feature')
```

The above feature calls this feature. I am trying to set the capabilities of chrome as mentioned [here](https://karatelabs.github.io/karate/karate-core/#webdriversession)

```
Feature: Example UI Test

    Background:
        This is just a simple example of UI testing.
        For more info: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/tree/develop/karate-core#webdriverurl
        * configure driver = { type: 'chromedriver', start: false, webDriverUrl: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub' }
        # * def session = { capabilities: { acceptInsecureCerts: true, alwaysMatch: { browserName: 'chrome', 'goog:chromeOptions': { args: [ '--headless', 'window-size=1280,720' ] } } } }
        # * def session = { capabilities: { acceptInsecureCerts: true } }
        # * configure driver = { type: 'chromedriver', webDriverSession: '#(session)', start: false, webDriverUrl: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub' }


    @ignore
    Scenario: Sample UI Automation Test
        * karate.call('ExampleUITestCommon.feature')
```

The feature above calls this feature

```
Feature: Example UI Test Common Tests to be used with each driver instance

    @ignore
    Scenario: Sample UI Automation Test Google
        Given def searchBarXpath = "//textarea[@type='search']"
        Given def googleSearchButtonXpath = "///input[@role='button' and @value='Google Search']"
        Given def googleSearchResultHeaderXpath = "//h3[text()='Karate UI']"
        Given driver 'https://google.com'
        And match driver.title == 'Google'
        And waitFor(searchBarXpath)
        And input(searchBarXpath, 'karate ui automation')
        And click(googleSearchButtonXpath)
        Then waitFor(googleSearchResultHeaderXpath)
```

I am using this to run the docker container. Here I am using the -s flag which is mentioned [here](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/tree/master/karate-netty#ssl)

```
docker run -it --rm -v ${PWD}/src:/src -w /src --name "karate-jre" --network host karate-jre java -jar /karate.jar  -s .
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `configure ssl` syntax applies only to the HTTP client used for API tests.

For WebDriver, what you need to adjust is the `httpConfig` key in the driver config. Refer to this part of the documentation: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/tree/master/karate-core#configure-driver (and search for `httpConfig`).

And within the `httpConfig` JSON you can nest anything described [here](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#configure). For example:

```
* def httpConfig = { ssl: true }
* configure driver = { type: 'chromedriver', httpConfig: '#(httpConfig)' webDriverSession: '#(session)', start: false, webDriverUrl: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub' }
```

Comment: Thank you so much Peter for that quick response.